# Is output of convolution of sinusoidal with itself, also sinusoidal?

Tags: convolution

Ladies, Gentlemen,

In my last question I asked you present the convolution of sinusoidal with itself. I accept Mr Peter K.'s answer. Now my question is much more important. Is output of convolution of sinusoidal with itself, also sinusoidal?

Regards

Comment: Mr Moderator, from Mr Dilip Sarwate answer: "When a linear filter is excited by a tone at frequency f1, the steady-state output is a tone at frequency f1" I conclude that  when some frequency (tone) is convoluted by an equal frequency, output is same frequency that is sinusoidal function. Then I ask you what is the scalar or amplitude of output 0, -0.9045, -1.11, 0.7725, 2.5, 0.7725, 0.2135, -0.9045, 0 for indeed samples of sine function should lie between -1 including and 1 including. Regards